# read txt file and create folder from single line

Tags: python, file-io, directory

I have a `list.txt` with simple names (for example: Test). Now I want to read the `txt` file and create a folder with the name Test. Every single line in `list.txt` should be a single folder.

I tried the following but it does not work:

```
def makefolder():
    with open('list.txt', 'r') as list:
        for line in list:
            os.mkdir()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

txtfile = open('test.txt', 'r')
lines = txtfile.readlines()
for line in lines:
        os.mkdir(line.rstrip("\n")) #inserting the name and taking out \n
```

I think you would need to remove the "\n" string to make the folders

Comment: i just have to modify my root path and it works. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
def makefolder():
    with open('list.txt', 'r') as list:
        for line in list:
            os.mkdir(line.strip())
makefolder()
```

you were missing to give the path as an argument in the `os.mkdir(path)` so in your code could be `os.mkdir(line)`
just add `strip()` method will help you to remove extra spaces